# Uninstall Ubuntu TV

Tags: uninstall, compiling, ubuntu-tv

i was testing and installed Ubuntu TV via instructions which can be found here. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing

But how do I remove it? `make uninstall` doesn't work and I am stuck. It is not my productivity machine, but would be nice to know for learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Can_I_do_.22make_uninstall.22_with_CMake.3F), you have two options:

1. Change the uninstall target at the end of CMakeLists.txt. It appears that the target in the existing code may be incorrect, and should read as follows:

```
   add_custom_target(uninstall
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake)
```

1. Run the command `xargs rm < install_manifest.txt`. This removes all of the installed files, but circumvents the `make` process.